# How can I simulate packet loss for my Qt UDP program?

Tags: c++, testing, networking, udp

As a homework assignment, I wrote UDP server-client application that tries to correct errors in the UDP communication using checksums and through confirming correctly received packets.

The problem is that on localhost, all packets are received without a problem. I tried some packet tampering programs, but they all require communication through network interface.

How to simulate UDP packet loss on localhost loopback address?

Answer (score 4):

UDP is easy to deal with--just write a bit of code in the sender or receiver which drops a certain percentage of the messages, and perhaps occasionally reorders some too.

If you can't modify the actual sender or receiver, it is easy enough to write a third program which simply sits in the middle, forwarding packets with some drops and reordering.

If you're using Linux, you can probably set up `iptables` to drop packets for you: http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/03/11/simulating-dropped-packets-aka-crappy-internets-with-iptables/ - this seems like it might work even on loopback ports.

Comment: I can modify the sender and receiver, but I wanted to be able to easily demonstrate the functionality without recompiling the program. I work mainly on windows but can test on linux if necessary.

Comment: @TomášZato: Well then just make it a configuration or command line option.